# How to clear everything from a single website in Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Is there a way to clear everything from a single domain (let's say .foo.com) in Chrome?

I mean

- History
- Website Cache
- Any Credentials
- Any Cookies
- Anything else I missed

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried developer tools under Google Chrome. If I recall that allows you to delete all data for a particular site?

1. Open chrome on the site.
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
3. Go to application.
4. Click clear site data.